# How to update Cells dynamically in Primefaces Data Table

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've a scenario Like i'll use cell Edit in Data Table.
I've two cells 
I've 1st Cell is Editable 
2nd Cell Value needs to be Displayed by doing some arithmetic operations on 1st Cell input (Eg: 2nd cell value =(1st cell value)*.14

My Code is Like

```
<p:dataTable id="cars2" var="car" value="#{dtEditView.cars2}" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellCars">.

<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{dtEditView.onCellEdit}" update=":form:msgs" />

       <p:column headerText="Cell 1">
              <p:cellEditor>
                  <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.id}" /></f:facet>
                  <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{car.id}" style="width:96%"/>
<p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{car.yearupdate}" update="2:3"></p:ajax></f:facet>
              </p:cellEditor>
          </p:column>
          <p:column id="2" headerText="Cell 2">

               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText id="3" value="#{car.year}" /></f:facet>

       </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

I want to Know the Java Code for Listener method code to update the 2nd cell value

Answer (score 0):

In xhtml we need to call the listener (p:ajax tag).

in bean update the other column data in bulk ( iterate over all search records and update corressponding valuefor all recs ) .. 
 xhtml code like

```html
<p:dataTable id="listDetails" value="${managedBean.searchList}" var="row">
  
  <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{managedBean.onRowEdit}"
        update=":managedBean:messages" />
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{managedBean.onRowCancel}" update=":managedBean:messages" />
  
  <p:column priority="17"
        headerText="col 1"
        styleClass="wrap text-right" style="width: 140px;">
        <p:cellEditor>
         <f:facet name="output">
          <h:outputText value="#{row.val1}" />
         </f:facet>
         <f:facet name="input">
          <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{row.val1}"
           <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{managed.valueUpdate}"
            update="tempValue></p:ajax>
          </p:inputText>
         </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
       </p:column>

<p:column priority="2" headerText="Col 2" exportable="true">
 <p:cellEditor>
  <f:facet name="output">
   <h:outputText id="value" value="#{row.value}" />
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="input">
   <h:outputText id="tempValue" value="#{row.tempValue}" />
  </f:facet>
 </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

in Bean

public void valueUpdate(){

```
    for (BO bo : searchList) {
        if(bo.val1!=null)
        {
        bo.value = bo.val1+50; // here u can do calc and assihn to the 
        bo.tempValue=bo.value;
        }
    }
```

}